# Orientation of a rocket going in a circle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, vectors

This problem is from my physics homework:

> A rocket is moving at constant speed in a perfect circle in deep space, far away from any planets or stars. The diagram below shows the circle the ship follows along with 4 points labeled A, B, C, and D during the rocket's motion.

Basically here' there's a diagram of a circle with the top, bottom, left, and four points evenly spaced around the edges, dividing the circle into quarters.

> Sketch the circle on your written homework and on your sketch show how the rocket must be oriented at each of the 4 labeled points. Clearly show which way the front end of the rocket points and also clearly show which end of the rocket has the rocket engine. Tell whether the engine is firing, or not. (This part is graded by hand, not online.)

There's a clip art of a rocket, but it only has one engine, so I'm not quite sure how the propulsion is supposed to work.

So here's what I know: if the rocket is going around in a circle, it's constantly accelerating towards the center. But it's not actually going towards the center, so I assume it's not pointed towards the center. Would it be pointed tangent to the circle? Or would it be aimed inwards slightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undergoing uniform circular motion, so its linear velocity is tangential to the circle, and its acceleration is towards the centre of the circle.

You can easily prove that it is tangential using calculus on complex numbers;

Let $z=Re^{i \theta}=x+iy$
Differentiating both sides with respect to time, 
$\frac{dz}{dt}=Ri e^{i \theta}*\omega=i \omega z$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

This means that the linear velocity is tangential to any point on the locus given by $|z|=R$.

differentiating again, $\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}=-R \omega^2z$, so the acceleration is perpendicular to the particle, directed inwards towards the centre.

Now, the rocket is going in uniform circular motion- hence it has an acceleration directed towards the centre of the circle. In addition, as it is in deep space far away from other masses, we can neglect the gravitational attraction due to those objects. The only possible source for the centripetal force is hence the propulsive force of the engines.

As it is directed towards the centre of the circle, I imagine that the rocket would be pointed inwards towards the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Circular motion is a motion with acceleration, because the velocity vector is changed during the motion. Therefore the engine must be on all the time, and the resulting force is changing the rockets velocity vector's direction, but not size (under other circumstances than those give in the question, the rocket could be using this same propulsive force to change the velocity size and/or direction, but then the motion wouldn't be a circle).

Since the velocity is constant in size, the acceleration vector must be perpendicular to the velocity vector (otherwise there would be a projection of the acceleration vector on the velocity vector, causing its size to change).

Remember that the velocity vector is always tangent to the path, by definition, because the body is advancing in the direction of the velocity vector, and your path is a circle.

According to newton's law, the direction of the acceleration is the direction of the total force applied, so assuming there's no vector thrust (i.e. the engine is creating thrust only in the axis of the rocket), the nose of the rocket must point towards the centre of the circle. This is similar to the earth and the moon: there's a gravitational force acting on the moon, perpendicular to its circular path.

The method to create such a dynamics in real life, is by "throwing" the rocket into space with angular velocity, and then adjusting the thrust until a steady circle motion is reached, with the nose pointing into the centre of the circle.